# What could be the warn color using material design when the primary color is red?

Tags: material-design, angular-material

Hi I am building a new web site with material design (angular-material). The main/branding color is red, obviously it is the primary color. What then could be the warn color or the accent color? especially in the form where the input are by default designed in red due to the primary color, what then could be the warn color? color that will show the user that there is an error with the field?

Comment: Not coming at this as a professional graphic designer, but perhaps you could accentuate it by changing the background color in those erroneous cases. Maybe you can solve it by displaying an icon in the field or next to it with an exclamation mark or something alone those lines. Perhaps merely a complementary hue like cyan or something in that range of the spectrum would do. Probably for an error/warning, most important is to be obnoxious and make it stick out (contrasty) rather than trying to pick the most harmonious color scheme that blends in with the rest. It's not the kind of thing [...]

Comment: [...] that's always going to be showing up and affecting the look of the site, but when it shows up, probably the most important quality is that it isn't easily overlooked -- contrast, in which case complementary colors, an inversion of foreground/background, a glaring icon -- all of these could serve that purpose.

Comment: now that it's passed 5 years, how have you managed this problem?

Comment: moved to react ... years ago